# How to use socket.io with only EJS without JS code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, ejs

Here is my code in EJS which receives data in real time from my node server based on certain parameters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>
<body class="container">

<header>
    <% include ../partials/header %>
</header>

<main>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>IsOnline</th>
          <th>Location</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
      <tbody id="tableData"></tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('status', function(data){
    var k = '<tbody>'
    for(i = 0;i < data.length; i++){
        k+= '<tr>';
        k+= '<td>' + data[i].url + '</td>';
        k+= '<td align="justify">' + data[i].name + '</td>';
        k+= '<td align="justify" width="30%">' + data[i].status + '</td>';
        k+= '<td align="justify" width="30%">' + data[i].loc + '</td>';
        k+= '</tr>';
    }
    k+='</tbody>';
    document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = k;
  });
 </script>
</main>

<footer>
    <% include ../partials/footer %>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

This code works perfectly fine but,
I have 2 questions :

1. I can not figure out a clean way to change text color of value of IsOnline based on condition eg: if user is offline then text should be `Offline` in red color else green.
2. Also I've created this table using js and html as data variable was not available in EJS so is there some way to get this variable. I do not want to send data using `res.render()` or `ejs.compile()`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
for(i = 0;i < data.length; i++){
    var color = data[i].status === "Offline" ? "red" : "green"; // If status is 'Offline', use red. If not use green

    k+= '<tr>';
    k+= '<td>' + data[i].url + '</td>';
    k+= '<td align="justify">' + data[i].name + '</td>';
    k+= '<td align="justify" width="30%" style="color: ' + color + '">' + data[i].status + '</td>';
    k+= '<td align="justify" width="30%">' + data[i].loc + '</td>';
    k+= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I tried doing inline styling just for testing purpose but it was not working either something like this:   ```k+= '<td width="30%" style="color:red">' + data[i].status + '</td>';```

Comment: See my updated answer, I used some mock data to test it and it works for me.

Comment: Yes I tried that and it's working, still I am stuck with second question